# Why is this 'moved' a past form?

Tags: tense

> "There must be some kind of story or legend behind it[=entrance
>   stone]. Maybe it's famous and on display at a shrine or
>   someplace."
>  "It could be, I suppose."
>  "Or maybe it's just in
>   some house, and people use it as a weight when they make pickles."
>   "No, that's not possible."
>  "Why not?"
>  "Because nobody can
>   move the stone."
>  "Nobody except you, you mean."
>  "Yes, I
>   think Nakata probably can."
>  "After you move it, then what?"
>   Nakata did an uncharacteristic thing––he pondered this for a good long
>   time.
>  At least he looked like he was, briskly rubbing his short,
>   salt-and-pepper hair.
>  "I don't really know about that," he
>   finally said. "All I know is it's about time somebody ***moved***
>   it."
>  Hoshino did some pondering himself. "And that somebody's
>   you, right? At least for now." 
> (Kafka on the Shore, tr. by Philip
>   Gabriel)

Why is ***moved*** a past form; is it a kind of subjunctive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a past form, it's subjunctive.

Another way of putting it is, "It's about time somebody **should move** it."